# Error parsing json request from expressjs morgan winston middleware

Tags: javascript, json, express, winston, morgan

I would like to parse the request and request body returned by **Morgan** middleware to **Winston** stream function.

I tried to use `JSON.parse()` but it gives error `uncaughtException: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

```
 morgan.token('reqBody', function (req: any, res: any) {
  return JSON.stringify(req.body)
 });
```

My Winston config code:

```
 module.exports.stream = {
 write: function (message: any, encoding: string) {

    console.log('req:', message);
 }
```

Output:

```
{"remote_addr":"::1", "id":"2ebb876e-6d42-4087-bc80-f2a617dd6bc3", 
"remote_user":"-","date":"26/Aug/2019:15:29:00+0000","method":"POST","url":"/department/2/employees","http_version":"1.1","status":"400","result_length":"16","referrer":"-","user_agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.15.2","response_time":"206.975","request_body":"{"name":"John Chris","Type":"C"}","response_body":"-"}
```

When I print the request `JSON` it shows above in ***Winston*** config and I am not able to parse it. As you might have noticed the req object, request_body is a child object and starts with `"{ "name: "John Chris".....}"`. I'm not sure the extra quotes with braces are causing an issue, but I couldn't figure out a way to parse it. If morgan returns just `req.body` instead of `JSON.stringify(req.body)` then i get `[Object object]` which I again failed to parse.

Comment: I don't know what Winston/Morgan are. But I strongly suspect that you should remove the `JSON.stringify`. `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` is what you get when you try to `JSON.parse` something that's already been parsed. It expects a string, so it coerces it to a string which is `[object Object]`. The `[` is valid - it could be a JSON array. But the `o` isn't - no valid JSON string starts with `[o`. that's why it says it's an `o` in position 1 (0-based). But I don't understand the last half of your last sentence, unless you've replaced `,` with `+` in the `console.log`.